# RS485 Rx signal connected with two drivers

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, driver, rs485, interface

I wonder why is RS485_Rx is connected with two line drivers while RS485_Tx is connected with only one line driver. Is this some mistake in the schematics or is it some standard circuit for RS485?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. The pairs in red circles are typical differential RS-485 input and outputs. The pairs do not have the same names, so this maybe a node unit.

Comment: I am concerned about the red circle on RHS, namely RS485_Rx.. it is connected with two drivers U27a and U29a.. that confuses me..

Comment: It was something of an answer so I had to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U27a receive and U29a receive are isolated by R123 680 ohms. MPU should have control but this addition implies that both receivers may be active at the same time. *In that case U27a will always dominate over U29a*. If U27a is NOT in receive mode (it goes to high impedance if RE\ is high) then R123 allows data from U29a to be read. A simple and crude priority switch.

The resistor is there to prevent a short if both receivers drive the same wire with no current limiting, which is what R123 is really there for.